# Xamarin FOrms routing with passing parameters in Shell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my codeBehind of my Page1 I have:

```
        {
            //do not select item
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

            //go to stockDetailsPage
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("postlogin/stockdetails?tickerSymbol=AAPL.NASDAQ");
        }
```

As you can see I hardcoded the value in order to test it.

Earlier it was without param, and it work, now I need to pass param `tickerSymbol`.
And in my stockDetailsPage in my ViewModel I added

`[QueryProperty("TickerSymbol", "tickerSymbol")]` above my class

and in my class I declared properties:

```
        public string TickerSymbol
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref tickerSymbol, Uri.UnescapeDataString(value)); }
            get { return tickerSymbol; }
        }
```

So in my constructor of that vm, I now want to call method with input argument of that param, but Im getting `null` all the time.

Can you suggest me where Im wrong?

Comment: Looks good about how you pass the param and the QueryProperty, please attach more code about the SetProperty function

Comment: I didnt understand you - what is SetProperty function?

Comment: Sorry, I go through your question again, are you putting QueryProperty on your ViewModel class? You probably need to move this to your stockDetailsPage.

Comment: @NicoleLu yes, Im trying to grab this param on my ViewModel class. Is it possible, or just I can grab it in codebehind? If so, how to pass data then from codebehind to vm?

Answer (score 7):

As Xamarin [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data) said it should be able to pass param to the class for the page's BindingContext, I tried the following and it works:

in code behind, set BindingContext to your ViewModel:

```
TestParamViewModel testParamViewModel;
public TestPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   testParamViewModel = new TestParamViewModel();
   this.BindingContext = testParamViewModel;
}
```

Add QueryPropertyAttribute to your ViewModel:

```
[QueryProperty("Name", "name")]
class TestParamViewModel
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            name = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

call navigation:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("testpage?name=Abyssinian");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and how can I use this name property? I want to trigger some method in my constructor, but it seems that that method `DoSOmething(name)` is triggered before property has been set, so my name prop is null?

Comment: yes you're right, the setter is called after the constructor, if you use name in constructor it would be null.